# R: Why won't my function create objects in my environment

Tags: r, function, for-loop, sampling

I want to write a function that will create *n* random samples of a data set without replacement.

In this example I am using the iris data set.
The iris data set has 150 observations and say I want 10 samples.

**My attempt:**

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)    

# load the data
data(iris)
head(iris)

# name df
df = iris

# set the number of samples
n = 10

# assumption: the number of observations in df is divisible by n
# set the number of observations in each sample
m = nrow(df)/n

# create a column called row to contain initial row index
df$row = rownames(df)

# define the for loop
# that creates n separate data sets
# with m number of rows in each data set

for(i in 1:n){
  # create the sample
  sample = sample_n(df, m, replace = FALSE) 

  # name the sample 'dsi'
  x = assign(paste("ds",i,sep=""),sample)

  # remove 'dsi' from df
  df = df[!(df$row %in% x$row),]

}
```

When I run this code I get what I want.
I get the random samples named ds1,ds2,...,ds10.

**Now when I try to turn it into a function:**

```
samplez <- function(df,n){

  df$row = rownames(df)

  m = nrow(df)/n

  for(i in 1:n){

    sample = sample_n(df, m, replace = FALSE) 

    x = assign(paste("ds",i,sep=""),sample)

    df = df[!(df$row %in% x$row),]

  }

}
```

Nothing happens when I execute 'samplez(iris,10)'. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Your function won't return a value unless you explicitly return one. For example, between the last two braces, add `df` to return `df` to the parent environment.

Comment: @eipi10 true, do you know how to get my samples to appear in the environment?

Comment: You mean you want to return not only `df`, but also the value of `sample` for each iteration of the loop? By the way, there's no need for `x = assign(paste("ds",i,sep=""),sample)`. This is equivalent to `x = sample`. But there's not need for that either, because you can do `df = df[!(df$row %in% sample$row),]`.

Comment: I'd like the samples, ds1,ds2... to be objects appearing in my environment. Kinda like what happens how if I run the loop normally without the function.

Comment: I think you should probably return a list to avoid cluttering your environment, where each element of the list is ds1, ds2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just save the results in a list and return that. Then you'll have a single object, the list of samples, in your global environment, rather than cluttering up your environment with a bunch of similar data frames.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `df`, but here is how to return all of the samples. Let me know what you want to do with `df` and I can add that as well:

```
samplez <- function(df,n){

  samples = list()

  df$row = rownames(df)

  m = nrow(df)/n

  for(i in 1:n){

    samples[[paste0("ds",i)]] = sample_n(df, m, replace = FALSE) 

    df = df[!(df$row %in% samples[[i]]$row),]

  }
  return(samples)
}
```

Comment: Yay thank you, just what I needed. I forgot about lists.